# Py Telegram Bot как получить file_unique_id фотографии

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я смотрел документацию Telegram Bot Api, и там для Photosize был параметр file_unique_id и file_name. Однако на практике они отсутствуют, максимум есть просто file_id, размеры и путь к файлу в чате. А мне нужно получить file_unique_id или file_name (желательно первый). Если кому известно, отпишите как их можно получить. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Согласно документации https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize
Для photosize нет параметра file_name, где вы его нашли в описании?

Вот так это выглядит для видео.

```
 file_id = dict(await bot.send_audio(message.chat.id, title=title, audio=audio, duration=duration, reply_markup=keyboard))
```

Что бы получать file_name его нужно передавать
за это отвечает параметр title, который указан в первом примере.

[image: Скрин]

```
 a = dict(await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=str(pokemon_list[1])))
```

[image: фото]

send_photo не имеет параметра file_name

Comment: Поздновато отвечаю, но всё же
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize

Comment: @IanFaint а чем моя ссылка не устроила?